# How to open IBM Application Center console?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded MobileFirst Developer Kit and now I want to open Ibm Application Center. In the tutorial says that "When you install MobileFirst Foundation, the Application Center is automatically installed in the specified application server." I enter the address "http://localhost:9080/appcenterconsole/" in web browser but I get the error "Context Root Not Found". The address "http://localhost:9080/mfpconsole" works. What do I need to do to open application center console?

Comment: Maybe follow instructions [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/appcenter-console/#starting-the-application-center-console) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MobileFirst Developer Kit does not include the Application Center.  Application Center is only available in the full (paid) version of the product.